# Python Script - button controllers problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyautogui import click, scroll

# Set up the Selenium webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Use the appropriate driver for your browser (e.g., ChromeDriver)

# Define the URL of the webpage you want to reload
url = "https://example.com"

# Define the refresh interval in seconds
refresh_interval = 12

# Function to clear the refresh time limiter cache
def clear_refresh_cache():
    driver.execute_script("window.performance.clearResourceTimings();")

# Open the webpage
driver.get(url)

# Wait for 6 seconds before starting the reloading process
time.sleep(6)

while True:
    # Reload the webpage 9 times
    for i in range(9):
        driver.refresh()
        clear_refresh_cache()
        time.sleep(refresh_interval)

    # Wait for 60 seconds before starting the next loop
    time.sleep(60)

# Add a command line to stop the refresh on mouse left click
left_click_event = pyautogui.event.MouseEvent(pyautogui.BUTTON.LEFT, 0, 0)
driver.execute_script("window.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { window.stop(); });")
driver.execute_script("window.addEventListener('click', function() { window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); });")

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Hi everyone, I want the given webpage reloads every 9 second 12 times and then take a break for 60 seconds, after the break the reload proceess starting again. But I want to stop only the reload process when I click on left mouse button.

This script written by AI, everything is working except left mouse click. When I click on it, it doesnt react to the process. Please help to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: you need to put the `left_click_event` inside or in front of the `while` loop... otherwise the code will never reach this point.

Comment: also you should read the docs to handle the mouse. This is useful: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html , otherwise you have basically posted the generic rubbish that the AI model has spewed out to keep you happy :)

Comment: Yes I'm not a developer :) I'm just trying to learn the python. I just put the 'left_click_event' before while and nothing happen. VS code says that the event function is unknown. I'll try with pynput package :)) Thanks a lot for response.

Comment: yes,  i was going to add that too.  the AI models are very helpful, but they make fundamental errors on technical things quite often. The entire second part of the code would not work...  if you use a code editor like `vs code` it would highlight a lot of the errors for you.  hope those tips are helpful.